# How to use where in Lambda expression

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, lambda

I have 4 textboxes [name=txtone, name=txttwo, name=txtthree, name=txtfour]. Also I have  a search button. In the button click event, I want to do the search in a table the input for the search are those text boxes which I given above. I am using Entity Framework and lambda expression to load the datagrid .

The code I am using ..

```
     var result = Entities.pos.ToList()
           .OrderBy(x => x.ID)           
           .Skip(initialRow)           
            .Take(finalRow - initialRow) ;     
            this.datagrid1.ItemsSource = result;
```

How can I use the where condition in this? And also one more thing, in that search no fields are mandatory. database table fields are [ID,NAME,AGE,DOB]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
var result = pO2GOEntities.po2go_gm_pos
           .Where(x=>x.SomeCoulumn ==txtone.Text || x.SomeCoulumn == txttwo.Text ---------)
           .OrderBy(x => x.ID)           
           .Skip(initialRow)           
           .Take(finalRow - initialRow)
           .ToList() ;     
            this.datagrid1.ItemsSource = result;
```

### UPDATE:

you can do like this then:

```
 var result = pO2GOEntities.po2go_gm_pos.ToList();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtone.Text))
    {
        result = result.Where(x=>x.SomeCoulmn == txtone.Text);
    }
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txttow.Text))
    {
        result = result.Where(x=>x.SomeCoulmn == txttwo.Text);
    }
--------------
--------------
--------------

var finalResult = result.OrderBy(x => x.ID)           
                        .Skip(initialRow)           
                        .Take(finalRow - initialRow)
                        .ToList() ;
```

Comment: this is fine .. But In these case If I click on the search button I wont get any record until and unless I pass any of the search in put. My condition is that I need to include the contion in where clouse only if I have any value enterd in the textboxes

Comment: it is Or condition so it will handle it you don't need to check the value, but if you want to you can check that as well

Comment: I Implimented this code and If I click on the Search button with out giving any values in the textboxes, then the datagrid.itemsource is null

Comment: what I mean to say , that Basically i dont want to include the condition If i didnt give the value in to the any of the textbox.

Comment: if you wish to do that way you can check with if before putting with where

Comment: can u please just demonstrate it , if you dont mind.

Comment: thanks, But I have 4 text box what if I given the values in the first and third text box it will take only the last condition rit? or I need to write  the condition for all possible combination ?

Comment: you have to check for all four if textbox not empty filter records on the base of its value

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.where** and specify the conditions.
Take a look into this [101 Linq Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b).

**Edit1:**

```
 var result = pO2GOEntities.po2go_gm_pos
       .Where(x=>x.clmOne==txtone.Text || x.clmTwo== txttwo.Text|| x.clmThree==txtThree.text || x.clmFour==txtFour.text)
       ..
       .ToList() ;     
 this.datagrid1.ItemsSource = result;
```

**Edit2:**
If the parameter is empty then where clause excludes it.

```
 var result = pO2GOEntities.po2go_gm_pos
       .Where( (x=>x.clmOne==txtone.Text || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1))&&  (x.clmTwo==txtTwo.text || string.IsNullOrEmpty(param1)) && ..)
       ..
       .ToList() ;
```

Comment: this is fine .. But In these case If I click on the search button I wont get any record until and unless I pass any of the search in put. My condition is that I need to include the contion in where clouse only if I have any value enterd in the textboxes